# Pandas Python - How to create a subset of two columns

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a dataframe with many columns that have a different department records (the rows include information that needs to be averaged). Right now I have two columns, "city" and "month". I am trying to get the average number for each department that is grouped by the subset of "city" and "months". I am able to get the "city" as a subset (see below). But I am looking for some tips or advice on how I would accomplish both. Sorry I am relatively new to Python and pandas.

My code:

```
new = df.DataFrame(columns = ['city', 'month']
cit = old['city'].unique()
for i in range(len(cit)):
   c = cit[i]
   subset = old[old['city'] == c]
   a = subset['dept records A'].mean()
   b = subset['dept records B'].mean()
   tbl = tbl.append({'city':c,'dept records A':a,'dept records B':b})
```

What I was thinking:

```
cit = old['city'].unique()
mon = old['month'].unique()

    for i in range(len(cit)):
       for j in range(len(mon)):
           c = cit[i]
           m = mon[j]
           subset = old[old['city'] == c, old['month'] == m]
```

Comment: Pandas has a groupby function for this type of operation. Try something like `old.groupby(("city", "month")).mean()["dept records A", "dept records B"]`

Comment: @Colin better slice before `mean` for efficiency ;)

Comment: Thank you @Colin I was able to accomplish my task using the group by function. Also thank you to mozway. I added the slice.